# Acceder a los datos dentro de otras tablas php

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

llevo varias dias formulandome esta pregunta y no encuentro solucion, espero que me puedan ayudar.

Tengo esta tabla principal donde almaceno todos los datos, dentro de esta tengo dos casillas que son foraneas de otras tablas que provienen de un select que son las tablas "id_shape" y "id_material" ya que si el cliente elige ya se 1 o 2 el resultado sera completamente diferente porque es otra opcion

[image: tabla principal donde van todos los datos]

Tabla donde se almacena datos para un select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El punto es que necesito es poder sacar los datos "nombre" y "precio" dentro de las tablas foraneas para poderas ocuparlas en otras partes del programa.

Estoy ocupando esta sentencia para poder sacar los datos, pero no me sale el error **Undefined array key "id_material"**

```
            inner join material using (id_material)
            where
            id_material = '".$_GET['id_material']."'");
        $id_material = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
          echo $id_material['nombre'];
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría usar los aliases de sql, en otras palabras los *AS*. Por ejemplo: Sabemos que tienes 3 tablas las cuales están relacionadas entre sí a través de llaves foráneas. Tu sentencia debería quedar algo como esto:

```
SELECT *.q, m.name as material_name, sc.name as shape_name
FROM quotes AS q
INNER JOIN material AS m
   ON m.id = q.id_material
INNER JOIN shape_cat as sc
   ON sc.id = q.id_shape
WHERE q.id_material = ?;
```

Eso te traería tus registros de qoutes y además la información de las tablas que escogiste

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación pero no la entiendo muy bien, no se si podrias explicarme mas detalladamente porque soy algo nuevo en esto de los inner joins o ayudarme dentro de esto, tal vez puedo contactarte?

Comment: Claro, con gusto. De todas formas te explico: un AS es simplemente el nombre con el que reconocerás las tablas. lo que haces es llamar cada uno. Luego cuando quieres seleccionar tus datos, dices qué datos quieres traer, es decir, no solo de la tabla desde que haces el form, sino también de las relacionadas.

Comment: Creo que debería ser `q.*` en lugar de `*.q`. Aparte de eso... ¡Buena respuesta!